# ¿Qué tan problemático es que el participante no haya mirado lo básico en un diccionario?

Tags: soporte, motivos-de-cierre

Leí [una pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20757/9385):

> Cuando se usa para describir una cantidad grande, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre montón y montaña? Al principio, pensaba que se usa montón con sustantivos masculinos y montaña con sustantivos femeninos, pero acabo de escuchar "un montón de cosas" y entonces ahora no estoy seguro de nada.

y quisiera preguntar ¿por qué toleramos que el que hace la pregunta no haya hecho ningún esfuerzo por buscar la respuesta él mismo?  En [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) se cierran las preguntas así.

¿Será porque es un sitio pequeñito de pocos participantes?

Comment: Relacionado: [Are general definition questions allowed?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/167/1674). Las respuestas de Flimzy y Gilles son muy instructivas.

Comment: Tienes razón en que a la pregunta le falta algo esencial: enseñar qué investigación ha hecho. Por ello lo recomendable es comentárselo primero para que añada esa parte; si no aparece, después de un tiempo prudencial no estaría de más cerrarla. Lo que no entiendo tampoco es que reciba votos positivos.

Comment: Muchas preguntas se hacen en este sitio sin investigación previa, pero si vemos que la pregunta tiene algo de interesante, aunque sea mínimanente, tendemos a pasar la mano. Según mi opinión, mientras [Spanish.SE] sea un sitio en beta debemos hacerlo así, para no asustar a la gente a la primera de cambio (en muchos casos es la primera pregunta del usuario). Mejor responderle y darle un pequeño aviso que asustarlo y que no vuelva. Cuando salgamos de beta y tengamos más usuarios activos podremos ponernos más estrictos.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo con @CarlosAlejo (por cierto, ese comentario es una posible respuesta a esta pregunta de meta. Yo la votaría, pues estoy de acuerdo). Solo añadir que puede resultar engañoso decidir qué recursos de aceptan como "oficiales" para demostrar esfuerzo previo.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Sí, creo que lo que escribiste sería la respuesta.  Es muy cierto que algunos sitios de SE no son muy amables para con los principiantes, pero Spanish Language SE tiene un ambiente muy positivo.

Comment: @Diego pues hale, comentario ampliado y publicado como respuesta. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Como sitio en fase beta (el lunes que viene hacemos 2000 días en beta), nuestro objetivo es coger una masa crítica de usuarios activos y, como dicen, ávidos. Las estadísticas se pueden consultar en el [Área 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) y, como podéis comprobar, la única estadística que se nos resiste es la del número de preguntas por día. Necesitamos que ese número pase de 5 y se mantenga así durante un periodo de tiempo considerable (10 sería lo ideal). Sin embargo, el sitio se mantiene desde hace bastante tiempo rondando las 4-4,5 preguntas al día. Hay semanas en los que veo que el número baja de 4, y días en los que veo que casi llega a 5 (en ocasiones muy puntuales hemos superado ese número, al ser una estadística que solo tiene en cuenta los últimos 15 días; ayer estaba en 4,9).

¿Todo esto a qué viene? Pues a que no podemos ser demasiado estrictos con las preguntas (todavía). Yo mismo reconozco haber hecho alguna pregunta sin investigación previa, con tal de aportar preguntas al sitio. Y mucha gente las hace así porque llegan de nuevos y no conocen la filosofía del sitio. Mi opinión es que si las preguntas que se hacen tienen algo, lo que sea, que pueda ser mínimamente interesante y pueda aportar al sitio, pues se responde y listo. El objetivo es no asustar a la gente nada más llegar, cerrándole preguntas sin más. En ocasiones no hay más remedio, porque la pregunta no está clara, o ya ha sido respondida, o es alguien queriendo que le hagamos los deberes. Pero si lo único que le pasa a la pregunta es que le falta investigación y aparentemente es fácil de responder, creo que es mejor responder a la pregunta y, como mucho, guiarle hacia las páginas del tour y de cómo preguntar, para que vaya afinando la puntería para próximas preguntas (nadie nace sabiendo, yo también metí la pata al principio alguna que otra vez). En el caso de que la pregunta deba ser cerrada porque no hay más remedio, se le explica amablemente el motivo y se le anima a mejorar, como sé perfectamente que hace la gente aquí.

¿Y adónde redirigimos a un usuario que no sabe cómo hacer consultas para su investigación? Pues a nuestra fantástica [página de recursos para aprender español](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2514/12637). Sí, el enlace está permanentemente en la página principal, pero como he aprendido a lo largo de los años, la gente no lee. Salvo que sea la respuesta a su pregunta, claro. Así que en la respuesta a la pregunta se le puede incluir el modo en el que podría haber consultado él mismo dicha respuesta, para que aprenda no sólo la solución a su problema, sino a todos los problemas similares que pueda tener. Especialmente si es un usuario de karma 1 (y en menor medida los de karma 101).

Resumiendo: creo que de momento en caso de duda es mejor responder a la pregunta si la única norma que viola es la de la investigación previa, para así atraer a la gente e impedir que salga despavorida de aquí. Ya cuando el sitio salga de beta y las preguntas nos desborden por las orejas tendremos ocasión de empezar a ponernos un poco más puntillosos.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. Quiero aclarar que no se trata de sacrificar contenido de calidad en pro de "cantidad" para pasar de Beta, objetivo que ya hemos asumido que es a muy largo plazo. Se trata de prioritizar **usuarios y contenido** sobre "reglas". Las reglas deberían ayudar para generar contenido de mayor calidad, pero por supuesto deben ayudar a generar contenido primero y fidelizar usuarios. Comentarios (y votos) deberían servir mejor que "cerrar y punto". Es necesario ayudar a los nuevos a entender cómo hacer posts de calidad y crear un ambiente amigable y productivo en la comunidad.